# Abuse of delete privilege - is there a mechanism to prevent self-interested moderators from using this as censorship to their own benefit?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, meta, moderation

I posted a question about problems with downvoting - it was well researched with great examples and included references.

It got deleted: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408037/how-do-we-request-stackoverflow-features-proposal-to-eliminate-the-downvote-f

That does not appear to be a justified action: censorship of all discussion on a topic by an elite few is abusing a privilege.

Who reviews deletions? How do we propose one for review? Can inappropriate use have that privilege revoked?

Comment: *it was well researched with great examples*: I disagree. You failed to include what past discussions you found here on Meta, let alone address those discussions. Stack Overflow has 12.5 years of history, and while details of our voting system have changed over time, the specific changes you envisioned are neither new nor are they likely to be implemented as they are fundamental to how the site works and its success. If you want to affect change in this area you need to start by showing awareness of this history *at the very least*.

Comment: A meta note:  the term “moderators” without further clarification is generally understood here to mean [one of the elected site moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators). The post was not deleted by a site moderator, it was deleted because three individual *community members* with the [deletion voting privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) cast a delete vote on that question. For a post like yours, lacking in some *extremely crucial research*, that is quite normal and not a form of abuse.

Comment: If you seriously wanted to discuss how the site works, start by reading [the central FAQ on how to effectively participate on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying). For future reference: the site moderators can review deletions, you can request that we look into a specific post and see if we need to intervene by flagging it for moderator attention. We can also send private messages to users and issue suspensions. In this specific case, I don’t see anything abusive in the deletion of your post, sorry.

Comment: “it was well researched with great examples and included references.” - Your question was most definitely not well researched.

Comment: ...not specifically.  Do you have any substantive evidence that supports addressing this issue?  Imma guessing no.

Answer (score 12):

(Creating this answer for future reference.)

Rest assured that the site's moderators know when they should intervene against rushed deletions. Even if they were not paying full attention at what was going on, you can flag the post for moderator attention explaining the situation and wait for the flag to be handled.

On the other hand, these were not cases of excessively rushed deletion. It was to protect everyone from the OP's streak of non-constructive stances regarding the platform.

Rest assured that we had reached a point where the OP was incapable of listening to feedback, persistently creating a war against an essential voting mechanism, providing misleading data, and even in past years going as far as to call a portion of our user base ignorant and somehow evil. That alone is in violation of site's policy.

Ultimately, having a user's posts constantly deleted like this is no longer about censorship. A private website does not have to host someone's bad takes. This is about showing people the door when they become a problem.